# How do I restore old Empathy logs from a previous installation?

Tags: 11.04, empathy

I'm an absolute beginner at all of this.  Please could someone CLEARLY explain (without assumption of any prior knowledge of operating Ubuntu, let alone 11.04) how I restore old Empathy logs now that I have 11.04.  I know that I kept my old stuff in a partition but I don't know what to do to bring it back.  The man who did this to my machine managed it last time but I'm without him and clueless.  Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can restore saved logs only if your Ubuntu installation as been upgraded from a previous version or if you (or the man who supported you) backed up your data in advance.
Reading your question I understand your helper put all your old data in a separate partition/position.

If so, first of all, ask him where he put your old data, and take a note: from now on I'll call this path `<OLD-PARTITION>`.
Then, note your user name: it is the name you can read in the top-right corner of your desktop in Ubuntu 11.04. I'll call this `<your-new-username>` from now on.
Same for your old user-name before upgrading (in case it was different): `<your-old-username>`.

Now, open Nautilus, the file browser. If you don't know how to do, just open a terminal and type `nautilus <OLD-PARTITION>`.

Now you shall browse till you reach the path below. Starting from the `<OLD-PARTION>` part, you only need to right click folders between "/" to reach it. If you cannot see the `.local` folder, press `CTRL+H` in *Nautilus* to show hidden files. Once you reach the "TpLogger" folder, right click on the "logs" folder and select `Copy`:

`<OLD-PARTITION>/home/<your-old-username>/.local/share/TpLogger/logs`

Then, do the same to restore, using following path.  Once you reach the "TpLogger" folder, right click folder list and select `Paste`:

`/home/<your-new-username>/.local/share/TpLogger/logs`

After this, restart *Empathy*.

Comment: Thanks.  But I don't know what I need to open to find that path!  If you could please elaborate (i.e. 'open Terminal', type this, do that...).  That would be great.  Thanks - sorry to be so ignorant but it's a complete mystery to me.

Comment: OK, I'll try to update and elaborate the answer.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks.  See, I did say beginner and I meant it! :-)

Comment: You welcome! If it worked, please mark my answer as appropriate ;>)